# How to fix iframe Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options

Tags: jquery, iframe

I can't this to work. I got the lightbox to work i got the a link that was clicked to be inserted in to the youtube src, but i get this Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Option error. Can someone explain this.

```
var $this = $(this),
      use_iframe =true,
      url = $this.attr('href'),
      name = $this.html(),
      // replace = false,
      $frame = $('#frame');





  var createvideoBox = function () {

      $('<div class="overlay"></div>').appendTo('#container');

      $frame.css({
        'top' : 50 + 'px',
        'position': 'fixed',
        'left' : 50 +'%',
        'margin-left' : -370 +'px',
        'width' : 1110 +'px',
        'z-index' : 2,
        'display' : 'block',
        'backgroundColor' : 'white'
      });

  }




  //  =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-= //
  // // – Trigger Event 
  // // =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-= 

      $('a').on("click", function(event) {

        var url = $(this).attr('href');

                  // console.log(url);

    // $('iframe').attr('src', url);

       createvideoBox();

          if(use_iframe) {

              $('iframe').attr('src', url);

          } else {

            window.open(url,name,replace);  

          }


          ///Prevent link execution 
          event.preventDefault();

        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you're trying to frame a YouTube `/watch` page, like:

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oHg5SJYRHA0
```

YouTube's frame options don't permit that — that page isn't really suitable for framing anyway. Frame the `/embed` page instead:

```
http://www.youtube.com/embed/oHg5SJYRHA0
```

There's no general solution for all links like this, though — many web sites (including most of Google's properties) have frame options which prohibit framing. If you need this to work for all links, you're out of luck; there's no way to do it.